# regular expression capture Group

Tags: regex

I have two regular expressions, A and B as indicated below, for extracting values from a string. When used independently they work as expected but when combined, as in C, I do not get the expected output from A
They are

```
A. (?<VALUES>\"[^\"]*\") and
B. (HEADER\=(?<HEADERS>\w+\s*\w+)\/?\,?)+\,((?<FIELDS>[\w\.?]+\:+[\w\s\.]+)\/?\,?)+
```

The combined regular expression is indicated below.

```
C. (HEADER\=(?<HEADERS>\w+\s*\w+)\/?\,?)+\,((?<FIELDS>[\w\.?]+\:+[\w\s\.]+)\/?\,?)+(?<VALUES>\"[^\"]*\")
```

I'm running the regular expression using Ultrapico's expresso version 3 tool.

Here is the string I'm working with

```
D. HEADER=FIELD CUST/HEADER=FIELD CUST,ACC::Account Number/LIM.REF::Limit/TYPE::Acct Type/CCY::Ccy/VALUED::Working Balance,""      "","110668    " "CUDJOE COMFORT                          ","03 OCT 2016","5501810001106681"     "     " "Ord. Sav. Acct."       "GHS"   "               5.86"
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try the following `(HEADER\=(?<HEADERS>\w+(?:\s+\w+)?)/?,?)+,(?:(?<FIELDS>[\w.?]+:+[\w\s.]+)/?,?)+|(?<VALUES>"[^"]*")` (can't stop SO from adding zero-width joiners into the comments :(, please just try joining your patterns with `|`).

Comment: See [this](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(HEADER%5c%3d(%3f%3cHEADERS%3e%5cw%2b(%3f%3a%5cs%2b%5cw%2b)%3f)%2f%3f%2c%3f)%2b%2c(%3f%3a(%3f%3cFIELDS%3e%5b%5cw.%3f%e2%80%8c%e2%80%8b%5d%2b%3a%2b%5b%5cw%5cs.%5d%2b)%2f%3f%2c%3f)%2b%7c(%3f%3cVALUES%3e%22%5b%5e%22%5d*%22)&i=HEADER%3dFIELD+CUST%2fHEADER%3dFIELD+CUST%2cACC%3a%3aAccount+Number%2fLIM.REF%3a%3aLimit%2fTYPE%3a%3aAcct+Type%2fCCY%3a%3aCcy%2fVALUED%3a%3aWorking+Balance%2c%22%22++++++%22%22%2c%22110668++++%22+%22CUDJOE+COMFORT++++++++++++++++++++++++++%22)